# Best way to store Text?

Tags: sql-server, text

Guys I know this question been answered a lot but I guess it is different depending on the scenario so here it is, I want to store guitar chords (song lyrics and their chords) so what is the best way to do something pretty similar to this:
http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/c/coldplay/dont_panic_crd.htm
do you have any idea what is the technique used here? just to help get a head start would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you really ask which datatype is needed for "text" ?
Do you use MS SQL or did you just use this tag as a placeholder for any database?

Comment: Not really I know there are a lot of types to use my question is a technically speaking which is the best way and why since I'm new to this

Comment: @DanFromGermany: In case you were talking about the `sql-server` tag, that isn't an *arbitrary database placeholder* tag. SQL Server is the name of a very specific product (or rather product line), the one you referred to as "MS SQL".

Comment: @AndriyM My guess was that the OP was thinking what you just explained to me. I know sql-server stands for the Microsoft database. Thx anyways!

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Ah, I see, I misunderstood your comment completely. Sorry! And thank *you* for setting me straight.

Answer (score 0):

If you need Unicode:

- **nvarchar(max)**
- **ntext(max)** (deprecated)

If you don't need Unicode:

- **varchar(max)**
- **text(max)** (deprecated)

All types store data volumes in an order of gigabyte.

Comment: Thanks for heads-up. The last time I checked the documentation was somewhere in 2010 (weren't deprecated back then). Answer edited.